# Is there any way to block SMTP email verifications with RCPT TO command?

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server, postfix-mta

I would like to learn if there is any way to block repetitive SMTP email verifications done by using RCPT TO: command. I'm using Postfix but I'll be happy to know if there are other MTA's with this feature.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to block **other** servers from doing this (verifying addresses on **your** server)?

Comment: yes, i would like to avoid verifications